# recieve output of multiple background uploads in bash script on mac os x

Tags: macos, bash, curl, ftp, background-process

I have a parent bash script that consequently launches another (child) script N times with different params. The child script uploads some files with `ftp` and `curl` and does some other stuff.

Now the goal is to accelerate parent script execution by moving uploading to background and display/analyze upload output after the parent script finishes executing all child scripts.

Any idea how to achieve this (and if it's possible at all)? My bash knowledge is rather poor unfortunately.

Actually, it's not strictly required to use shell scripting - it can be anything else (perl/python/ruby/etc.), but preferrably everything should be contained in the least amount of files.

Environment: Mac OS X Mavericks, default bash (v3.2).

Comment: Show your code; stating your script 'does some other stuff' is not the least bit helpful to anyone.

Comment: I don't think it really matters what it does. Anyway, it compiles Xcode project and produces .ipa and related files which are then uploaded.

Comment: Save the output to multiple files or shell variables or an array.

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating files and save everything in shell somehow. If it wasn't a background job, that would be easy.